# Mongoose findOneAndUpdate creates new record every time - also when conditions are met?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

The values in the conditions should be consistence with the data in the collection. However, every time i make a new findOneAndUpdate with the same data, it creates new records in the collection.

The data in my collection looks like this

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5bc2e6bea49c6200130e1efe"
    },
    "email": "c@c.com",
    "password": "c",
    "createdAt": {
        "$date": "2018-10-14T06:48:30.159Z"
    },
    "signedToEvents": [
        {
            "eventSignedDate": {
                "$date": "2018-10-15T18:42:37.879Z"
            },
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "5bc4e0717287250013b66907"
            },
            "event": {
                "$oid": "5b8ed4effb6fc013752b5e1e"
            },
            "isActive": true
        }
    ],
    "__v": 0
}
```

My call to looks like this:

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({_id : req.userId, "signedToEvents.event" : mongoose.Types.ObjectId(event._id)}, { $push : { 'signedToEvents': { event: event._id, isActive: true } } }, {upsert:true})
    .exec()
    .then(docs =>{
        res.status(200).send(docs);
    })
```

Please point me in the right direction

Comment: Try removing `"signedToEvents.event" : mongoose.Types.ObjectId(event._id)` from the query and see what happens.

Comment: Should it perhaps be `"signedToEvents._id" : mongoose.Types.ObjectId(event._id)`

Comment: Remove `_id : req.userId`. In most of the cases `upsert` with `_id` doesn't work. And also it doesn't make sense as well.

Comment: @Raj - this will make it work, but I would like it to in the condition.

Comment: @dnickless - thats the id of the element in the array.

Comment: @Anthony - The id must be a part of the condition

Comment: @Klaus N new records are getting created because the two conditions on which you are searching and updating records are not getting matched, hence your upsert property is creating a new record. Just try to make findOne(...) query and see if you get any record. Also you might want to check if "signedToEvents.event" should be passed an mongodb object id or simple string.

Comment: @Raj Thanks, it narrowed it down with just the search and found out the problem